# get products which contains both values of filter

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my table is

### product_id    filter_id

55                    1
55                    2
56                    1
57                    1

i wants product_id that contains both filter_id 1,2 but not that contains only 1 nor 2.

so my ans is only 55 product_id.

what's my sql query ?

Comment: Where is your code that you are working at?

Comment: i try select * from table where filter_id in (1,2) but it gaves me whole  table not only 55

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to solve it, depends on data amount and more precised conditions. For your particular case this query should fit. 
Also, good for you to check [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

```
select product_id
from my_table
group by product_id
having count(distinct filter_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
    SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id IN (
                    (SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE filter_id = 1)
            INTERSECT
                    (SELECT product_id FROM products WHERE filter_id = 2)
            );
```